# modify the file csv failed

Tags: java, csv, bufferedreader, bufferedwriter

I had created the service contains modify CSV file. I add value to last column each row but I found the problem when overwriting the file. if a new file has different name against an old file, it's success but I want the file with the same name. how to fix this problem?

```
public void modify() {
    BufferedReader br=null;
    BufferedWriter bw=null;

    try {
        File file = new File("C:\\Users\\c76266\\Documents\\bobby\\text\\sample2.csv");
        File newfile = new File("C:\\Users\\c76266\\Documents\\bobby\\text\\sample2_new.csv");

        br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream(file))) ;
        bw = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(new FileOutputStream(newfile)));

        String line = null;
        String [] addedColumn = {"newstring1", "newstring2"};
        int i=0;

        while((line = br.readLine())!=null){
            String result = "\t"+addedColumn[i];
            bw.write(line+result+System.lineSeparator());
            i++;
        }
    } catch(Exception e){
        System.out.println(e);
    } finally  {
        try {
            br.close();
            bw.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
}
```

in this code, working well because file and new file are a different name. **`sample2.csv`** and **`sample2_new.csv`** but I want the new file also **`sample2.csv`** but failed. when I opened a file, empty string. thanks.

Comment: Save the file contents onto a string and then write back the string to sample2.csv

Comment: You can't open file for both reading and writing at the same time using standard file operations - programming  languages are not text editors.. As soon as you open it for writing it gets truncated. Use a temp file instead. Read up on basic file operations.

Comment: Are you not catching any exception? Because you probably would get **ArrayindexOutofBoundsexception** if you have more than two lines.

Answer (score 0):

Save modified file with different name and after operation is done replace old file with the new temp file:

```
import static java.nio.file.StandardCopyOption.*;
...
Files.move(source, target, REPLACE_EXISTING);
```

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/move.html